# group custom module collection

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have created custom module, which contain same value in a column,i want to get collection which must be group by to that column.

```
Mage::getModel('test/test')->getCollection()->getSelect()->group('order_id');
```

but it's giving an error in reports.

```
"Unrecognized method 'setPageSize()'";i:1;s:5777:"#0 /home/15766-20131.cloudwaysapps.com/enshfhxhrz/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with this :

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $collection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/custom')->getCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()->group('column_2');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```